# Using Python3 modules in ROS2 packages

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I developed Python3 modules with code independent from ROS. Now I want to use them in a ROS2 package, more specifically I want to import them in a ROS2 node. The node listens to a ROS topic and should use my Python modules to work with the data provided by the topic.

However I couldn't find any information on how to achieve this. At first I tried to plug my modules next to the node, but when I tried to run the node after *colcon build* it was unable to import the modules, because *colcon build* runs the script in the *install* directory. So I modified the data_files in *setup.py* with

> data_files=[
> ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
> ['resource/' + package_name]),
> ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
> (os.path.join('share', package_name, 'dependencies'),
> glob('dependencies/*'))
> ],

and put my modules in the dependencies directory. Now I am unable to build the package, due to a colcon error

> Starting >>> tst_mapfusion_r2pp
>
> --- stderr: tst_mapfusion_r2pp error: cant't copy 'dependencies/fusion':
>
> doesn't exist or not a regular file
>
> --- Failed <<< tst_mapfusion_r2pp [0.45s, exited with code 1]
>
> Summary: 0 packages finished [0.74s]

> 1 package failed: tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> 1 package had stderr output: tst_mapfusion_r2pp

Whereas the dependencies directory contains the sub-directories for my modules, one of them being fusion.

Where do I have to put my own python modules in order to use them inside the ROS2 package? Is it possible without shenanigans like fiddling with *$PYTHONPATH*?

Edit: The tree is a bit extensive and I'm not allowed to upload files or pictures (new user -.- ). So please be patient with me.

> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> -build

> ---COLCON_IGNORE

> ---tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> ----build

> -----lib

> ------tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> -------**init**.py

> -------map_fusion.py

> ----colcon_build.rc

> ----colcon_command_prefix_setup_py.sh

> ----colcon_command_prefix_setup_py.sh.env

> ----dependencies

> -----fusion -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/dependencies/fusion

> -----importer -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/dependencies/importer

> -----misc -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/dependencies/misc

> -----opencv -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/dependencies/opencv

> ----package.xml -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/package.xml

> ----resource

> -----tst_mapfusion_r2pp -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/resource/tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> ----setup.cfg -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/setup.cfg

> ----setup.py -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp/setup.py

> ----tst_mapfusion_r2pp -> /root/ros2_ws/src/tst_mapfusion_r3pp/tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> ----tst_mapfusion_r2pp.egg-info

> -----PKG-INFO

> -----SOURCES.txt

> -----dependency_links.txt

> -----entry_points.txt

> -----requires.txt

> -----top_level.txt

> -----zip-safe

> -dependencies

> --fusion

> ---**pycache**

> ----map_fusion.cpython-38.pyc

> ---map_fusion.py

> --importer

> ---**init**.py

> ---**pycache**

> ----pgmloader.cpython-38.pyc

> ---pgmloader

> --misc

> ---**pycache**

> ----mp_misc.cpython-38.py

> ---mp_misc.py

> --opencv

> ---**pycache**

> ----ocvfmodule.cpython-38.pyc

> ---ocvfmodule.py

> -install

> -log

> -package.xml

> -resource

> -setup.cfg

> -setup.py

> -test

> -tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> --**init**.py

> --map_fusion.py

> -tst_mapfusion_r2pp.egg-info

> -venv

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371066/using-python3-modules-in-ros2-packages/) by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-02-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phillipov](https://answers.ros.org/users/69329/phillipov/) on 2021-02-05**:
For clarity, could you please run `tree ~/location_of_workspace/src/tst_mapfusion_r2pp` and update your question with the output? It should print a tree-like structure of all the files and directories.

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2021-02-08**:
My understanding is that the `data_files` option is only supposed to be used for extra stuff your code needs, not code itself. I would expect you would be fine just inserting your extra modules alongside the ROS-specific stuff that gets installed by the `packages` term in `setup.py`. This doesn't work?

**Comment by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) on 2021-02-08**:
I suspect, it's for ROS-packages. I've tried to add my dependencies here, but I got:
`error: package directory 'dependencies' does not exist`.

From my limited understanding, when writing a ROS2 node with Python; `colcon build` will copy the ROS code in the install folder, specified by setup.cfg and, for a lack of a better term, 'register' it for ROS2 to be found as run-able. So isn't it possible to tell colcon to copy my files in the proper directory when building?

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2021-02-08**:
`colcon build` is not doing anything more than invoking setuptools to install everything into the `install/` directory, the same way calling `python setup.py install` would. The stuff listed under the `packages` keywords are simply the python packages that will be placed under `install/`, which most likely should include these extra modules you mention.

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2021-02-08**:
In case you haven't seen it, you can understand how `setup.py` and the `packages` keyword work here: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html One thing that often trips people up is remembering a python package is only defined when an `__init__.py` file is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved. Thanks to jdlangs and phillipov.
With regard to the `setup.py` documentation I packed my modules in packages parallel to the node like that:

> src

> -tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> --tst_mapfusion_r2pp

> ---**init**.py

> ---map_fusion.py

> ---fusion

> ----**init**.py

> ----map_fusion.py

> ---importer

> ----**init**.py

> ----pgmloader.py

etc.

Furthermore, as jdlangs suggested I edited `setup.py`s packages section:
`packages[package_name, '{}'.fusion.(package_name), '{}'.importer(package_name)]` and so on for all my modules.

Additionally the import statements in my ROS2 node had to be edited from
`import fusion.map_fusion as fusion` to `from .fusion import map_fusion as fusion`

Unfortunately deeper dependencies like my misc package which is needed by my ocvfmodule require an import a level deeper, like `from ..misc import mp_misc`.

Thank you very much for answering my question, even if it turns out to be more of a general python question.

---

Originally posted by [NotARobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/69326/notarobot/) with karma: 109 on 2021-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2021-02-09**:
I believe it should also be possible to put your `fusion` package at the same level as `tst_mapfusion_r2pp` and have it installed as a separate top-level package. Then your original import statements would work.